# Firebase update field using variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function which should go ahead and update the database on firebase

```
function editUser() {
  var userID = document.getElementById('userID').value;
  var editUserField = document.getElementById('editUserField').value;
  var newUserValue = document.getElementById('newUserValue').value;

  var database = firebase.database().ref().child('users/' + userID);
  database.once("value", function(snapshot){
      console.log(snapshot.val());
  })

  database.update({
    editUserField: newUserValue
  })

}
```

The above code is sort of working. Its getting the correct user, but whats not happening is the field is not getting updated, but instead, its creating a new field in the database and assigning it the value.

Looks like a key pair value is getting passed in

```
editUserField: newUserValue
```

but its actually taking the value `editUserField`

rather than getting getting it from the input:

```
var editUserField = document.getElementById('editUserField').value;
```

The value is actually getting stored correct from:

```
var newUserValue = document.getElementById('newUserValue').value;
```

But it doesnot update the value for the correct key, instead creates a new field called `editUserField`

I need it to get the values from the input and update the fields in firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your intentions correctly, you want the field that is updated to be the value of `editUserField`.

As an example, if `editUserField` is `"favorite-food"` and `newUserValue` is `"pizza"`, you want `{ favorite-food: pizza }` to be added to the user's data.

If that's the case, you were very close, you just need to wrap `editUserField` in square brackets to use it's value:

```js
database.update({
  [editUserField]: newUserValue
})
```

Note: Don't forget to sanitise `editUserField`! You wouldn't want them setting `{ isAdmin: true }`.

Comment: I think I've spent a day trying to make it right, until I found this, thanks :)